# I'm trying to run the 'npm run dev' and I get the errors. I'm working on a project using laravel 9. I'm using Visual Studio Code as the code editor

Tags: node.js, laravel, webpack

I get this error :

> C:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\MVivant\webpack.mix.js:1 ��m
>
> SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
> at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
> at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:20)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1190:27)
> at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1280:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1089:32)
> at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:930:12)
> at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1113:19)
> at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
> at module.exports (C:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\MVivant\node_modules\laravel-mix\setup\webpack.config.js:11:5)
> at loadConfigByPath (C:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\MVivant\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:1445:37)

I'm trying to run 'npm run dev' command in my laravel 9 project